# Get the minimum value of array with the following code

Tags: php

I don't really understand the logic of the following:

```
$max = array_reduce($values, function($max, $i) {
    if (is_numeric($i) && $i > $max) {
        return $i;
        //echo $i."max";
    }
    return $max;

});
```

This will return the maximum value in array. How I can modify the above code to return the minimum value as long is numeric? This will help me understanding how this works. i am aware or min and max functions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Great thanks a lot. Not sure how to mark the question as answered :)

Comment: there is a check mark under the up/down voting arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You should break down code then and learn to debug what you have. This is a pretty straight forward piece of code:

```
// array_reduce — Iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function
//A callback is literally a function that is called for the logic and is started at function
//$values is your values, max is what was run from the last iteration and i is the current value.
$max = array_reduce($values, function($max, $i) {
    // Checking the value is numeric
    // AND 
    // $i is greater than $max
    if (is_numeric($i) && $i > $max) {
        //  If the above is true you have a number greater than the current
        //  max value return this iteration value.
        return $i;
        //echo $i."max";
    }
    // It will only reach here is the above is not true so return what was the max
    // example max = 5 i = 2 you will return 5
    return $max;
});
```

So you need to find what logic get the max in that which is this logic:

```
if (is_numeric($i) && $i > $max) {}
```

Now how can you make it the min well > is greater and < is less so:

```
if (is_numeric($i) && $i < $max) {}
```

would do the trick (kind of there is a bug) but is confusing because you call the var max personally I would re-write like this:

```
$min = array_reduce($values, function($min, $value) {
    //Has to check for a null min sets min to value if smaller
    if ((is_numeric($min) && $value < $min) || $min == null) {
        $min = $value;
        //echo $value."min";
    }
    return $min;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

the following code gets the job done. it compares the value of two positions in the array, deletes them and then stores the minimum value. thus reducing size of array by one in each step and continues repeating the procedure till array size becomes 1.

```
$mn = array_reduce($values, function($mn, $i) {
    if (is_numeric($i) && $i < $mn) {
        return $i;
        //echo $i."mn";
    }
    return $mn;

});
```

Comment: Include some explanations to your code. How does this help OP understand? That is the goal of OP, to understand and you just dump code. That is not a good answer.

Comment: added explaination.

Answer (score -1):

```
$min = array_reduce($values, function($carry, $i) {
    if (is_numeric($carry) && $i > $carry ) {
        return $carry;
    }
    return $i;

});
```

Comment: Include some explanations to your code. How does this help OP understand? That is the goal of OP, to understand and you just dump code. That is not a good answer.

Comment: Not only is there no explanation but this answer doesn't actually work.

Comment: @Nick It does work. It sets $min to the smallest number in the $values array. I've tested it twice now. In addition, the OP asked, "How can I modify the above code...This will help me understanding [sic] how this works." OP asked for modified code, not an explanation.

Comment: All answers on SO should hava en explanation.